# Query to show the device where a file is located. [ORACLE]

Tags: oracle, data-files

I am looking at the [ss64](http://ss64.com/orad/DBA_DATA_FILES.html) website, but I can not seem to show the device where my file "/home/user/file_data.dbf" is located.

In other words, the query would return the following information:

```
 -------------------------------------------
|          Datafile             |   device  |
|-------------------------------------------|
|  /home/user/file_data.dbf     |  /dev/sda |
|  /mnt/example/file_data2.dbf  |  /dev/sdb |
 -------------------------------------------
```

All help is grateful.

Comment: Can you edit your question please? Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with your tags: `sql`, `oracle`, `plsql`, `oracle12c`? I will delete them for you. In the future please pay attention to the tags at the bottom of your post.

Comment: @peter rockix What do you mean? First you are looking for a specific file and then you expect a result with two different files??

Comment: @mathguy I need an sql query and I also use oracle 12c. Where is the problem?

Comment: @mathguy, put Oracle tag back.

Comment: What do you mean by "device?"  the server machine name that the file resides on?

Comment: I ask again. What does any of this have to do with Oracle, pl/sql, etc.? Your question is an OS question. If you want to find out on what physical device your `/home` directory is, execute the Unix command `df /home`. Do you expect to find that information in the catalog tables? I very strongly doubt that you will find it there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what this has to do with Oracle, database etc. To find out where your folders are physically located, use the Unix command `df` (perhaps preceded by `host` if you want to do it from a SQL*Plus session). I don't think you will find this info in the catalog; Oracle only knows file and directory names, where they are physically located is the OS's business, not Oracle's.

Example:

```
SQL> host df /home
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      466218648 25089284 417423764   6% /
```